# Como incluir um arquivo externo Javascript no angular?

Tags: angular

Nos meus antigos projetos tive condições que aproveita boa parte dos meus códigos css quando comecei a criar meus projetos em Angular, ao pesquisa soube de um arquivo chamado styles.css que fica dentro da pasta src e dentro dela a pasta app.

Essa parte foi fácil, o que está sendo um desafio e como incluir meus antigos arquivos javascript

veja como eu lincava os meus arquivos javascript

```
<script src="assets/js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>


<script src="assets/js/lib/chart-js/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/dashboard.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/widgets.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/lib/vector-map/jquery.vmap.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/lib/vector-map/jquery.vmap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/lib/vector-map/jquery.vmap.sampledata.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/lib/vector-map/country/jquery.vmap.world.js"></script>
```

eu vasculhei no meu projeto angula e não encontrei uma forma de incluir-los no projeto, alguém poderia por gentileza me explicar para incluir-los no meu projeto?

eu tentei colocar assim;

```
<script src="js/teste.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Coloquei o arquivo teste.js dentro da pasta src e dentro da pasta src criei uma pasta js e coloquei ela lá dentro, mas não resolver e gerou um erro no console do navegador

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts

Comment: você está usando angular-cli?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma forma que estou usando é pegar essas chamadas e colocar na index do seu projeto angular, e jogar todo o conteúdo na pasta assets, isso vai fazer rolar, existem outras formas, só que mais trabalhosas, ainda mais quando se tem um template bootstrap pronto para passar para um projeto angular 2 ou superior